# What is the correct way of redirecting / rewrtiting traffic from HTTP to HTTPS in Ubuntu / Apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, webserver, https, apache-virtualhost

I'm learning about website hosting, and more and more YouTube sources recommend redirecting traffic from HTTP to HTTPS these days. I've found two ways this can be done, and I'd like to ask which one is the better/preferred way to do this in 2023.

Currently, I'm redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS using Virtual Host .conf files, so I'm not interested in .htaccess redirection at the moment.

The first way 2 redirect HTTP to HTTPS is this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName firstsnow.dev
   ServerAlias www.firstsnow.dev
   DocumentRoot /var/www/first
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   Redirect permanent / https://firstsnow.dev/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName firstsnow.dev
   ServerAlias www.firstsnow.dev
   DocumentRoot /var/www/first
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.firstsnow.dev'">
      Redirect permanent / https://firstsnow.dev/
   </If>
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstsnow.dev/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstsnow.dev/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I've found it [here](https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/). There's a date of this article, that states January 2020, so it looks like quite up to date knowledge.

But when I've installed an SSL certificate from CertBot using [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/WPPBO-QpiJ0), I've noticed, that the CertBot added this 4 lines, to my already existing `converse.conf` file (shown below):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName converse.nexus
   ServerAlias www.converse.nexus
   DocumentRoot /var/www/conv
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =converse.nexus [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.converse.nexus
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html
```

and created a separate `converse-le-ssl.conf` virtual host file.

This `RewriteEngine` is something entirely different from the first `Redirect permanent / https://firstsnow.dev/` method.
It not only looks and feels different but it also uses `%{SERVER_NAME}` env variable instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}` request header and I don't understand why.

## Can you please shed some light on this subject and explain the difference between these two ways of redirecting HTTP traffic and help me choose one that better suits my needs.

I'm just beginning to study web development and Linux administration and apache2 Virtual Hosts.
Currently I'm running 3 very simple websites using name based Virtual Hosts and the 4th one is on the way.

Comment: The rewrite done by LE is basically redirecting as well (the `R=permanent` flag). I personally prefer the `Redirect` directive.